# Run Nvidia-docker on Jetson nano and jetson xavier for deep learning framework like tensorflow

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-docker, nvidia-jetson-nano, jetson-xavier

I am currently trying to run Nvidia-docker on Jetson Xavier and jetson nano with the Tensorflow framework enabled inside. but the problem I’m facing right now is related to “libcublas.so”.

What I had tried the solution mentioned here:

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1043951/jetson-agx-xavier/docker-gpu-acceleration-on-jetson-agx-for-ubuntu-18-04-image/post/5296647/#5296647 1

All package installations (pip installs and apt-get installs) completed successfully but when I try to import TensorFlow from both Python 2.7 or 3.6, I get the following error:

ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
using Jetson Xavier or jetson nano?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo docker run --net=host --rm --runtime nvidia --ipc=host -v /tmp/.X11-unix/:/tmp/.X11-unix /tmp/argus_socket:/tmp/argus_socket --cap-add SYS_PTRACE -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -it [container]`

I'm assuming it would work on Host first.

---

Source: official forum but *up to date*.

Device is no longer used